# Intent.createChooser how to choose between two Intents

Tags: android, android-intent

So I want user to be able to open either Skype or phone's contact list.

```
    if (isPackageExists("com.skype.raider")){

       PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
       Intent skype = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.skype.raider");
       Intent contacts = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Contacts.CONTENT_URI); 


       Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(skype, "Talk");
       chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, contacts);

       startActivity(chooserIntent);       }
```

The chooserIntent doesn't show either one of the intents on the list.

**How to make simple chooser for two custom intents?**

Comment: A Chooser wont choose between Intents, it chooses between apps that can handle the intent you are trying to send.

Comment: So is the any way to utilize the intents methods for selecting between these two intents? We can show all apps on the chooser list or filter them. Seems like a serious flaw if these mechanics cannot be used to show a custom selection of intents. Making a whole new activity to select between two intent seems like an overkill for this task.

Comment: i dont really get what you are trying to do here, your are creating the intent to start skype and to start your Contacts app, at least thats what id guess. what is suppposed to happen if skype is installed

Comment: If skype is installed, the app asks from user would he like to open skype or default contacts. There are countless of situations where you would like to offer list of actions from custom set of intents. I assumed that this could be done easilly, but I guess I was wrong and I have to make new popup or activity for only to get user select which way he like to make a call.

Comment: cant you just put openSkype/openContacts into Menü in case Skype is installed?

Answer (score 0):

> The chooserIntent doesn't show either one of the intents on the list.

Let's leave aside for the moment that your Skype assumptions (forevermore using this package name, forevermore the launcher `Intent` is appropriate in this use case) have issues.

First, you are not using `EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS` correctly. [The documentation states that it is an array of `Intent` objects](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS), and you are not supplying an array.

Second, I am unclear if the chooser will show the `EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS` if they are not on the list of things supported by the underlying chooser `Intent`. In this case, Skype may not be in the roster returned by `queryIntentActivities(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Contacts.CONTENT_URI))`, and so Skype would not ordinarily be a choice in the chooser. I have never tried using `EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS` to effectively concatenate other semi-random `Intent` objects ("random" from the standpoint of the OS more so than the user in this case) onto the list of choices. It may work, but I certainly would not assume that it does.

> I assumed that this could be done easilly

Few developers would consider implementing a dialog box or `ListFragment` of `Intents` for the user to choose from to be especially complex.

> I have to make new popup or activity for only to get user select which way he like to make a call

That is entirely possible, if the aforementioned fixes do not work for you.